# Typescript not validating the contents of an object being spread to complete a type

Tags: typescript

I have an interface `IThing` and several interfaces that extend `Ithing`: `IThingA`, `IThingB`, etc.

```
interface IThing{
    id: string;
}

interface IThingA extends IThing{
    a1: string;
    a2: number;
}

interface IThingB extends IThing{
    b1: string;
}
```

I have a generic function that creates an `IThing` given a set of `props`:

```
function createThing<T extends IThing>(
    props: any = {}
): T {
    const thing: T = {
        id: newId(),
        ...props
    };
    return thing;
}
```

When I call the function:

```
const a1: string = "red";
const a2: number = 10;
const props = {a1}; //forgot to include a2
const thing: IThingA = createThing<IThingA>(props);
```

I would like Typescript to warn me if `props` doesn't contain all the properties required for the specific `IThing`.  In this case I forgot `a2` for `IThingA` and Typescript doesn't warn.

How can I achieve this check?

Comment: `props: Omit<T, 'id'>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Omit<interface, id> will help you.
So I Altered your code to match the requirements

```
function createThing<T extends IThing>(
    props: Omit<T, 'id'>
): T {
    const thing: T = {
        id: newId(),
        ...props
    } as T;
    return thing;
}
```

[full example in Ts Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)